# How to mix ResolutionStrategies with Gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

Let's say I have the following in my gradle build script:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {

    failOnVersionConflict()

    force 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    }
}
```

This will fail if more than one version of a jar is found, except for guava where it will force to version 18.0.

Now let's imagine that I want to have `failOnVersionConflict()` for all external jars, and be forced to use the force clause (so I know what I'm doing), but I want to use the default resolutionStrategy (newest version) for some specific group, like `com.mycompany`.

Is such a thing possible?

I was looking at this documentation page:

https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

Comment: There currently isn't a way to do this within a single configuration. Your only option would be to split those dependencies up across two separate configurations, and configure the resolution strategy for each. You could also add some logic to enforce this, i.e. don't allow external dependencies to be added to the 'internal' configuration.

Comment: Well, after viewing your comment and not finding anything, I decided to hack my own way through it... After all, that's what makes gradle cool... :) I posted it as an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my own answer... But it involves a bit of "hacking"... But, after all, that's just what gradle offers...

```
def dependencyErrors = 0

configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {

    def thirdPartyPackages = [:]
    def forced = [ 
        'com.google.guava:guava' : '18.0'
        //Here all forced dependencies...
    ]


     eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->


          if (!details.requested.group.startsWith('com.mycompany')) {

                def key = details.requested.group + ":" + details.requested.name
                if(!thirdPartyPackages.containsKey(key)) {
                    if(forced.containsKey(key)) {
                        details.useVersion forced.get(key)
                    }                   
                    else {
                        thirdPartyPackages.put(key, details.requested.version);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    def existing =  thirdPartyPackages.get(key);
                    if(existing != details.requested.version) {
                        logger.error "Conflicting versions for [$key]"
                        logger.error "    [$existing]"
                        logger.error "    [$details.requested.version]"
                        dependencyErrors++
                    }
                }
          }
      }

  }
}

myTask.doFirst {
  //here it might also be doLast, or whatever you need. I just put it before a war task, but it might depend on each need. 
  if(dependencyErrors > 0) {
    ant.fail 'There are ' + dependencyErrors + ' conflicting jar versions in the build.'
  }
}
```